# How to access Javadoc comments from a file?

Tags: java, parsing, javadoc

How would I access and parse the Javadoc comments properly? Either being from a java source file or from a generated Javadoc file would work.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im making an editor for a new language and it references some java clases and also uses javadoc. So I'm trying to access the Javadoc in order to make something like the Hover Javadoc info that Eclipse's Java editor presente when you are focused on a suggestion of the contentAssistant

Comment: I would suggest to have a look how IDEs like Eclipse and Netbeans do this. Maybe you can use the relevant library from one of them. (They both are open source.)

Comment: For the benefit of Googlers, try Javaparser (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and also see this question re. accessing Javadoc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563921/accessing-javadoc-with-javaparser-returns-null