# Accessing Javadoc with Javaparser returns null

Tags: java, javadoc, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I'm parsing Java source files with [Javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) *(javaparser-core 2.0.0)* to get Javadoc comments from methods.

However, I always get `null` When I call `MethodDeclaration.getJavaDoc()`. Looking at the source of `MethodDeclaration`, I can see why:

```
public JavadocComment getJavaDoc() {
    return null;
}
```

*(It appears Javadoc is available from `Node.getComment()` instead)*

My question is: Why is method Javadoc not available from `MethodDeclaration.getJavaDoc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: because we added the interface DocumentableNode but later we did not implemented correctly. Currently all nodes can have comments attached, however we wanted to add an interface to differentiate the nodes that could have a proper JavaDoc comment (technically you can add a Javadoc comment to a local variable but you shouldn't). Note that a ticket is already open for this issue https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/141

Disclaimer: I am a JavaParser contributor